# Collision in the Class

Tags: python, pygame

I am writing a code for a game (school project).
I have a Class with different images for objects. 
What I want is to create a condition for collision. For example, if the image if fire collides the image of earth then get a new image. 
How can I do it ?

Thank you!

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tiny Alchemist")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 90
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
ALTWHITE = (240, 240, 240)
clear = False           # Flag that shows if the user wants to clear the screen
class Element(pygame.Surface):
    def __init__(self, image, xpos, ypos):
        self.image = image
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos
        self.width =  image.get_width()
        self.height = image.get_height()
        self.selected = False
        self.visible = False
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(xpos, ypos, image.get_width(), image.get_height())

    def move(self, move):
        self.xpos += move[0]
        self.ypos += move[1]
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.xpos, self.ypos, self.width, self.height)

class Recycle(pygame.Surface):
    def __init__(self, xpos, ypos):
         self.image = pygame.image.load("ElementIcon/recycle.png").convert_alpha()
         self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (75, 75))
         self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
         self.xpos = xpos
         self.ypos = ypos
         self.rect = pygame.Rect(xpos, ypos, self.image.get_width(), self.image.get_height())

class PanelElements(pygame.Surface):
    def __init__ (self, image, xpos, ypos):
        self.image = image
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(xpos, ypos, image.get_width(), image.get_height())
        self.clicked = False


def init():
    global ImageList
    global Panel
    global recycle

    fire = pygame.image.load("ElementIcon/fire.png").convert_alpha()
    fire = pygame.transform.scale(fire, (50, 69))
    fire.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    fire_mini = pygame.transform.scale(fire, (40,50))
    fire_mini.set_colorkey(ALTWHITE)

    earth = pygame.image.load("ElementIcon/earth.png").convert_alpha()
    earth = pygame.transform.scale(earth, (50, 69))
    earth.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    earth_mini = pygame.transform.scale(earth, (40, 50))
    earth_mini.set_colorkey(ALTWHITE)

    water = pygame.image.load("ElementIcon/water.png").convert_alpha()
    water = pygame.transform.scale(water, (50, 69))
    water.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    water_mini = pygame.transform.scale(water, (40, 50))
    water_mini.set_colorkey(ALTWHITE)

    wind = pygame.image.load("ElementIcon/wind.png").convert_alpha()
    wind = pygame.transform.scale(wind, (50, 69))
    wind.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    wind_mini = pygame.transform.scale(wind, (40, 50))
    wind_mini.set_colorkey(ALTWHITE)

    energy = pygame.image.load("ElementIcon/energy.png").convert_alpha()
    energy = pygame.transform.scale(energy, (50, 69))
    energy.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    energy_mini = pygame.transform.scale(energy, (40, 50))
    energy_mini.set_colorkey(ALTWHITE)

    recycle = Recycle(650, 718)

    fire_mini_obj = PanelElements(fire_mini, 750, 10)
    earth_mini_obj = PanelElements(earth_mini, 750, 60)
    water_mini_obj = PanelElements(water_mini, 750, 110)
    wind_mini_obj = PanelElements(wind_mini, 750, 160)

    fire_obj = Element(fire, 362, 460)
    fire_obj.visible = True
    earth_obj = Element(earth, 300, 410)
    earth_obj.visible = True
    water_obj = Element(water, 365, 350)
    water_obj.visible = True
    wind_obj = Element(wind, 420, 409)
    wind_obj.visible = True


    Panel = []                 #adding elements to the list
    Panel.append(fire_mini_obj) 
    Panel.append(earth_mini_obj)
    Panel.append(water_mini_obj)
    Panel.append(wind_mini_obj)

    ImageList =[]               #adding elements to the list
    ImageList.append(fire_obj)
    ImageList.append(earth_obj)
    ImageList.append(water_obj)
    ImageList.append(wind_obj)

def run():

    global done
    done = False
    while done == False:
        check_events()
        update()
        clock.tick(60)      

def check_events():
    global done
    global ImageList
    global Panel
    global recycle
    global clear

    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
            print("User quits the game :(")
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                done = True
                print("Game stopped early by user :( ")

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for im in ImageList:
                if im.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and (im.visible == True):
                    im.selected = True
            if recycle.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                clear = True
            for mini in Panel:
                if mini.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    mini.clicked = True




        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            for im in ImageList:
                if im.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and im.visible == True:
                    im.selected = False


        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            for im in ImageList:
                if im.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and im.selected and (im.visible == True):
                    xmv = event.rel[0]
                    ymv = event.rel[1]

                    if event.buttons[0]:
                        if xmv < 0:
                            if im.xpos > 0:
                                im.move((xmv,0))

                        elif event.rel[0] > 0:
                            if im.xpos < screen.get_width():
                                im.move((xmv,0))

                        elif ymv < 0:
                            if im.ypos > 0:
                                im.move((0,ymv))

                        elif event.rel[1] > 0:
                            if im.ypos < screen.get_height():
                                im.move((0,ymv))
    #pygame.display.update()

def update():
    global ImageList
    global Panel
    global recycle
    global clear
    screen.fill(WHITE) 

    #Update the screen with drawings
    for im in ImageList:
        if im.visible == True:
            screen.blit(im.image, (im.xpos, im.ypos))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, ALTWHITE, (740, 0, 160, 800), 0)

    for mini in Panel:
        screen.blit(mini.image, (mini.xpos, mini.ypos))                  

    screen.blit(recycle.image, (recycle.xpos, recycle.ypos))
    if (clear == True):
        for im in ImageList:
            im.visible = False
     clear = False

    for i in range(0,len(Panel)):
        if Panel[i].clicked == True:

            Panel[i].clicked = False

    pygame.display.update() 

if __name__=="__main__":
    init()
    run()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: checking if pixels touch/overlap?  math?  probably some built in functions of pygame?  You should post what you've tried and we'll help debug.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this:

```
earth = pygame.image.load("earth.png").convert()
earthRect = earth.get_rect()
fire = pygame.image.load("fire.png").convert()
fireRect = fire.get_rect()

if earth.colliderect(fire):
    earth = pygame.image.load("thirdimage.png")
```

with the first four lines defining our images and the rect objects used to detect collision, the last two line detecting the collision and changing the image file

Comment: If the objects collide I want to create a new object of a Class and add it to the List

Comment: you can do all of that in the if statement